# Change color of JButton without changing its shape

Tags: java, swing

I want to change the color of JButton by:

```
JButton button = new JButton();

button.setBackground(Color.decode("#00a5ff"));
```

In order for change to occur, I have to add:

```
button.setOpaque(true);
button.setBorderPainted(false);
```

However, this remove the curves around the edges and thus changes the shape of the button. Is there a way to just simply change to color and keep the other properties? Another example is the changing of color (getting darker) when you press a button without having changed its color.

Here is some code that illustrates the difference between the two buttons:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("frame");
    frame.setSize(new Dimension(300, 300));
    JButton button1 = new JButton();
    JButton button2 = new JButton();

    button1.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100,100));
    button2.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100,100));
    button2.setBackground(Color.decode("#00a5ff"));
    button2.setBorderPainted(false);
    button2.setOpaque(true);

    JPanel pane1 = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
    JPanel pane2 = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());

    pane1.add(button1);
    pane2.add(button2);
    frame.add(pane1, BorderLayout.WEST);
    frame.add(pane2, BorderLayout.EAST);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

Thanks

Comment: In most cases, this is controlled by the look and feel delegate, which may or may not provide you means to change it (I'm pretty sure that Windows L&F doesn't - even if you extend the implementation, it's all done through private functionality :P)

Answer (score 0):

I literally just tested the following:

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame("frame");
frame.setSize(new Dimension(300, 300));
JButton button = new JButton();

button.setBackground(Color.decode("#00a5ff"));
frame.add(button);
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
frame.setVisible(true);
```

It seemed to work, but I am working on Ubuntu Studio 16.04. If you notice that it does not work, then let me know. Could you please show the result of your white button or your failed button (if it still doesn't work)?

Comment: Most Native Look and Feels don't fill the button via the background, but via the `contentAreaFilled` property which generates the "shape" of the button, making the `background` property somewhat useless

Comment: This does not work, as the color does not change. I am using a Mac. In order for the color to change, I have to do `button.setBorderPainted(false);` which removes the smooth edges and other properties of the button and makes it a rectangle with that color.

Comment: @MadProgrammer Do you know how to merely change the color and not mess with the shape? I think Netbeans was able to do that in design studio, however, what lines of code are necessary?

Comment: @Playdowin No, as I said, this is governed by the L&F and unless it provides some "super secret properties" (something like Nimbus), then it's near impossible to to do

Comment: @MadProgrammer I wrote an example to display the difference

Comment: @MadProgrammer This was automatically possible when using Netbeans Design Studio, I do not know why it would be impossible when writing code manually.

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps you have something else going on in your code. I altered a small example I have and the color changes with only setBackground(Color) using regular Button and using JButton. See the following...

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Frame frame = new Frame();
    Panel panel = new Panel();
    Button closeButton = new Button("Close");
    closeButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            frame.setVisible(false);
            frame.dispose();
        }           
    });
    closeButton.setBackground(Color.decode("#00a5ff"));
    panel.add(closeButton);
    frame.add(panel);
    frame.setSize(200, 100);
    frame.setLocation(200, 50);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

Comment: This merely creates a white (standard button) with a blue border around it. Note that I am using a Mac.

Comment: I get a blue button, but I am on Win 10. I copied the code you added and I get the blue button with that as well.

Comment: The problem is not getting a blue button... The problem is that the button becomes a square (and not soft edges) as well as not getting darker when pressing it, as it does when not changing its color.